# matplotlib does not plot zeroes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, relu

Currently I am trying to plot a simple Relu function using matplotlib. My problem is that when plotting, matplotlib ignores the zeroes and does not plot them.

Heres my functions

```
def relu(t):
    t[t <= 0] = 0
    return t

def relu_plot():
    t = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)
    k = np.zeros(40)
    plt.plot(t, relu(t))
    plt.show()
    print(len(relu(t)))

relu_plot()
```

And here is what matplotlib returns
[image]

The plot works if I instead use an array of size 40 with only zeroes, and the relu function is indeed returning an array of size 40. Any help would be appreciated

Update: Instead of just plotting relu(t), I tried plotting a concatenated array as follows

```
    k = np.concatenate((np.zeros(20), j))
    plt.plot(t, k)
```

And it works as expected. I think then that it is a problem with how I changed the values to 0 in the relu function but I am not sure yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `relu` function modifies `t`, so using `t` for your x variable produces the unexpected results (no longer spanning -2 to 2, but 0 to 2).

```
def relu(t):
    return t.clip(min=0)
```

Output:

[image]